Scheduled refresh - ignore tables without connection
I have three data sources :
1. An Excel file that I loaded from my computer
2. A Sharepoint on Cloud
3. A Sharepoint on premise


So of course, I cannot connect on Powerbi Premium online to two of the three sources, so when I do a refresh I get an error. In Desktop -> transform data, I unchecked for those two sources "Include in report refresh".
When I ask for a scheduled refresh, I want to be able to refresh everything that it can connect to, or at least choose which sources refresh to.

"Include in report refresh" is unchecked.

I tried making Direct Query to the Cloud, but I cannot do visuals with mixing data sources, so it's useless.

Refreshing through Power Automate, I get the same problem.

Due to cybersecurity policy,  I cannot use an API key of the Azure database and refresh selected tables.



Your problem is with the datasource on Power BI service, follow this guide to create a connection on PBI service : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-create-share-cloud-data-sources
